# c++ command line with system calls

Tags: c++, shell

I'm writing a shell in c++, and I need a constructor for my CommandLine class that parses a command from the istream, and then uses the calloc() and free() system calls to dynamically create argc and argv variables.  I don't get how to use the system calls to do this, and no tutorial has helped.

Comment: can you expand your question a bit? Do you not know how to call calloc and free or do you not know how to use istream to read in the provided command line? Among other things since you are writting c++ code you should be using new and delete operators

Comment: @fumalaga: If you *must* use system calls, you *must* tell us which operating system it is for.

Comment: @wallyk He's referring to `calloc` and `free` as system calls.  (They're actually part of the C standard library.)  Of course, he's going to need system calls later to create the new process in which to run the generated command.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Upon re-reading the question, I see you are correct.  The problem before him is creating `argv[]` ready to call `exec()`; that does seem like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example very similar to what you're asking for. I found it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc

> function calloc
>
> void * calloc ( size_t num, size_t size );
>
> Allocate space for array in memory Allocates a block of memory for an
>   array of num elements, each of them size bytes long, and initializes
>   all its bits to zero.
>
> The effective result is the allocation of an zero-initialized memory
>   block of (num * size) bytes.
>
> Parameters
>
> num
>       Number of elements to be allocated. size
>       Size of elements.
>
> Return Value A pointer to the memory block allocated by the function.
>   The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be cast to the
>   desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable. If the
>   function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a NULL
>   pointer is returned.
>
> Example
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

```
/* calloc example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  int * pData;
  printf ("Amount of numbers to be entered: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  pData = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));
  if (pData==NULL) exit (1);
  for (n=0;n<i;n++)
  {
    printf ("Enter number #%d: ",n);
    scanf ("%d",&pData[n]);
  }
  printf ("You have entered: ");
  for (n=0;n<i;n++) printf ("%d ",pData[n]);
  free (pData);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use cplusplus.com, use cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @Griwes What's the difference?

Comment: Quality. cplusplus.com is often reffered to as "one of worst websites about c++".

Comment: People often say that; I've seen errors or omissions on both.